# pythonでJSONエラーのTypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray

Tags: python, python3, pdf

英文のPDFを読み込み、翻訳し、Outlookの下書きとして書き出しをしようと思っています。

(https://www.cpi-japan.com/services/ 一番上の「IELTSリーディングサンプル」のPDFファイルを使用)

下記部分でエラーが発生してしまうため、お力添え願いたいです。

```
例外が発生しました: TypeError
the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType
  File "C:\Users\NAME\Documents\練習用\2023_01_rensyuu\test7.py", line 27, in <module>
    result = tr.translate(txt_list, src="en", dest="ja").text
```

下記サイトを参考に作成しました。

- [PythonでPDFを読み込みテキストを抽出する（PyMuPDF）](https://python-work.com/pdf-get-text/)
- [【Python】gooletransを使って自動翻訳をやってみる。](https://plog.shinmaiblog.com/python-translator/)
- [PythonでOutlookの指定したアカウントの下に下書きを作る](https://gist.github.com/akilab/529c6954ddbc6024a0e8e2a381126e83)

バージョン：Python 3.9.15

```
#ライブラリ設定
import fitz # pymupdfライブラリ
import openpyxl as px 
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment
from googletrans import Translator
import json
 
#PDFテキストを格納するリスト作成
txt_list = []
 
# PDFファイルを読み込む
filename = 'IELTS.pdf'
doc = fitz.open(filename)


for page in range(len(doc)):
    text = doc[page].get_text()
    text = text.replace('\n', '')
    txt_list.append([page+1,text])


#翻訳する
tr = Translator()
result = tr.translate(txt_list, src="en", dest="ja").text
#↑エラー発生個所:print(result)


#outlookに下書きを作成
_VERSION_ = 'v0.1.0'
def show_version():
    print("=" * 20)
    print("Draft Creater VERSION {}".format(_VERSION_).center(20))
    print("=" * 20)

def main():
    show_version()
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")

    mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    # draft_box = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(16) # 16が下書きフォルダの番号らしい

    draft_box = mapi.Folders("自分のmailアドレス.co.jp").Folders("下書き")
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = 'to@example.com'
    mail.Subject = 'タイトル'
    mail.HtmlBody = result #←ここに翻訳結果の変数入れたい
    mail.Move(draft_box)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

**試したこと**

JSONで使えないオブジェクトエラーとのことでおそらく文字列型のオブジェクトに変換するのではないかと思い、エラー発生個所の前に下記コードを差し込みましたが例外が発生しました。

```
txt_list = json.loads(txt_list)
```

```
TypeError
the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list
  File "C:\Users\NAME\Documents\練習用\2023_01_rensyuu\test7.py", line 24, in <module>
    txt_list = json.loads(txt_list)
```

**追記**
頂いたコメントをもとに修正しました。(1/11)

```
#ライブラリ設定
import fitz # pymupdfライブラリ
import openpyxl as px 
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment
from googletrans import Translator #**変更箇所**pre-release版(4.0.0-rc1)をインストール
import json
import re
import sys #**変更箇所**追加
 
#PDFテキストを格納するリスト作成
txt_list = []
 
# PDFファイルを読み込む
filename = 'IELTS.pdf'
doc = fitz.open(filename)


for page in range(len(doc)):
    text = doc[page].get_text()
    text = text.replace('\n', '')
    txt_list.append(text)**#変更箇所・文字列のリストのみにした**

#print(txt_list)


#JSON変換
#txt_list = json.load(txt_list) 

#翻訳する
tr = Translator()
try:
    for pagetext in txt_list:
        # 1ページ分が１つの文字列で、それを日本語に翻訳
        result = tr.translate(pagetext, src="en", dest="ja").text
        #print(result) #★**ここでprintした場合の結果は以下参照**
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

""" 
tr = Translator()
result = tr.translate(txt_list, src="en", dest="ja") 
for results in result:
    print(results.origin, ' -> ', results.text)
"""


#outlookに下書きを作成
_VERSION_ = 'v0.1.0'
def show_version():
    print("=" * 20)
    print("Draft Creater VERSION {}".format(_VERSION_).center(20))
    print("=" * 20)


def main():
    show_version()
    pythoncom.CoInitialize() #**エラー発生個所**
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")

    mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    # draft_box = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(16) # 16が下書きフォルダの番号らしい

    draft_box = mapi.Folders("自分のメールアドレスco.jp").Folders("下書き")
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = 'to@example.com'
    mail.Subject = 'タイトル'
    mail.HtmlBody = result
    mail.Move(draft_box)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

**上記コード内のエラー発生個所のエラーメッセージ**

```
例外が発生しました: NameError
name 'pythoncom' is not defined
  File "C:\Users\NAME\Documents\練習用\2023_01_rensyuu\test7.py", line 68, in main
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
  File "C:\Users\NAME\Documents\練習用\2023_01_rensyuu\test7.py", line 83, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
```

**上記コード内★部分のprint結果**
ターミナルに表示されたものをwordに貼り付けて確認したが、
約２５文字ごとに改行がされているので改行なしのべた打ちにしたい。

```
CPI IELTS SAMPLES READING PASSING 1 PASSING 1に
は、1950年代のエチオピアでテレビ放映された陸上 
競技の出現以来、エチオピアの長年の成功以下のパ 
(文字数4039字のため省略)
```

Comment: `txt_list.append([page+1,text])`にて数値と文字列1つづつをリストにしたものを更にリストにしているものを`result = tr.translate(txt_list, src="en", dest="ja").text`で指定しているからでは？ [translate(text, dest='en', src='auto', **kwargs)](https://py-googletrans.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#googletrans.Translator.translate)でパラメータは`text (UTF-8 str; unicode; string sequence (list, tuple, iterator, generator))`となっていますが、おそらく指定出来るのは「文字列のリスト」であって、「「数値と文字列のリスト」のリスト」では無いと思われます。`txt_list.append([page+1,text])`を`txt_list.append(text)`にしてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: ありがとうございます。txt_list.append(text)にしたところ変わらず同じエラーが発生します。また、txt_list.append(text)にした上でJSON変換(やったこと参照txt_list = json.loads(txt_list))を行うと'list' object has no attribute 'read'のエラーが発生します。

Comment: もしかしたら`result = tr.translate(txt_list, src="en", dest="ja").text`で戻り値のオブジェクトにそのまま`.text`をメソッドチェインで適用しているからかもしれません。先に紹介した`translate`メソッドの説明の`Advanced usage:`に書いてあるように、パラメータにリストを指定すると戻り値がリストになるので、それを`for`ループで1個1個テキストに変換すれば良いのかもしれません。

Comment: @kunif ありがとうございます。 #翻訳する tr = Translator()以下にをtry: for page1 in page: result = tr.translate(txt_list, src="en", dest="ja").text except Exception as e: print(e)と書き込んでループさせたところ、今度は最終行の sys.exit(main())に例外が発生しました: NameError
name 'sys' is not defined

Comment: コメントでは表示が整形されないので、質問記事を編集して追記しましょう。それから試す内容が変な感じですね。PDFのページでループするのではなく、紹介した`Advanced usage:`のようにtranslateした結果のオブジェクトをループして列挙された個々の要素の`.text`を表示してみてください。

Comment: 修正不足でしょう。`result = tr.translate(txt_list, src="en", dest="ja").text`の行に`.text`が残っています。これを外して`result = tr.translate(txt_list, src="en", dest="ja")`にしてみてください。

Comment: @kunif .textを外しましたがresult = tr.translate(txt_list, src="en", dest="ja")行で上記エラーメッセージが変わらず発生して下のfor文の結果を表示することができません。

Comment: エラーメッセージが変わっていない(`.text`が付いたまま)なら、変更前のファイルを実行しているのでは？ 変更した後セーブしていますか？ あるいは別名でセーブしていて、変更前のファイル名で実行していませんか？

Comment: @kunif .text抜けでセーブ後実行しましたが、同じ箇所のエラーメッセージが変わっていません。『例外が発生しました: TypeError the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType』というのはそのままです。エラーメッセージから.textは無くなりました。この行でエラーが発生しているため下のfor文結果を表示できません。

Comment: そうすると`NoneType`というのが怪しそうですね。コメントアウトした`print(txt_list)`を有効にしてどのようなデータが表示されるか確かめましたか？ もしかしたら空のリストだったり、紹介記事の`Advanced usage:`に記述されているようなパラメータ内容とは違う形式のデータになっているのかもしれません。

Comment: @kunif コメントアウトしたprint(txt_list)を有効にしたところ
['CPI  IELTS Samples  Reading  READING PASSAGE 1 (中略) Vitamins and minerals    ']というリスト形式の文章が入っています。

Comment: これもコメントで返すのではなく、内容は略さずに記事に追記してください。長すぎる場合は呼び出す際のパラメータ自身を短くして試してみてください。もしかしたら1つの文字列が長すぎるのかもしれませんし、あるいは途中に変なデータが混じっているのかもしれませんから。

Comment: 試しに単独で仕様説明の例のとおりに入力してみたら何か訳の分からないエラーになって動作しませんでした。最終更新が2年半前なのと、こちらの注意書き [Note on library usage](https://py-googletrans.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#note-on-library-usage) の内容から、もしかしたら今はまともに動かない可能性も考えられます。あるいは色んなモジュールを使っているので、それらの版数アップ等により整合性が取れなくなったのかもしれません。

Comment: 結局最終的にこちらの問題かもしれませんね。[googletrans でエラーが出た場合は PRE-RELEASE で回避可能](https://sig9.org/archives/4023) googletransモジュールをpre-releaseの最新版にする必要がありそうです。

Answer (score 1):

内容的には自身で参照している以下の記事の内容を変更しようとして上手くいかなかった、ということでしょう。
[【Python】gooletransを使って自動翻訳をやってみる。](https://plog.shinmaiblog.com/python-translator/)
こちらの記事では googletrans に翻訳依頼するテキストをリスト等ではなく単一の文字列で指定しています。

それに対して質問のソースコードでは、おそらく高速化を意図したのでしょうが、文字列のリスト(当初は「「数値と文字列のリスト」のリスト」)を渡しています。
当初：「数値と文字列のリスト」のリスト

```
    txt_list.append([page+1,text])
```

変更：文字列のリスト

```
    txt_list.append(text) #**変更箇所・文字列のリストのみにした**
```

---

そして安定版の最新(3.0.0)のドキュメントでは、以下のように文字列のリストもパラメータに指定出来ていたのでしょうが：
[translate(text, dest='en', src='auto', **kwargs)](https://py-googletrans.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#googletrans.Translator.translate)

> - text (UTF-8 str; unicode; string sequence (list, tuple, iterator, generator)) – The source text(s) to be translated. Batch translation is supported via sequence input.

質問のソース(変更中のもの)

```
tr = Translator()
result = tr.translate(txt_list, src="en", dest="ja") #**エラー発生個所**
```

冒頭の記事やコメントで紹介した以下の記事にあるように安定版の最新(3.0.0)にはバグ(仕様変更？)があってpre-release版(4.0.0-rc1)を使う必要があるのでしょう。
[googletrans でエラーが出た場合は PRE-RELEASE で回避可能](https://sig9.org/archives/4023)

そしてどうもpre-release版(4.0.0-rc1)では文字列のリストをサポートしておらず、翻訳依頼するテキストを単一の文字列で指定する必要があるようです。
冒頭の記事や質問者さん自身の途中のコメントにあるように、以下のような形で出来るでしょう。`print(result)`の部分はoutlookに渡すためのデータ作成にする必要がありますが。

```
tr = Translator()
try:
    for pagetext in txt_list:
        # 1ページ分が１つの文字列で、それを日本語に翻訳
        result = tr.translate(pagetext, src="en", dest="ja").text
        print(result)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

---

ちなみにコメントで「今度は最終行の sys.exit(main())に例外が発生しました: NameError name 'sys' is not defined」となっていた部分は、それに対応する`import sys`が行われていないためですね。

---

**追記に対応して：**

NameError name 'pythoncom' is not definedエラーについては NameError name 'sys' is not definedと同様に、必要なimportが不足しているからですね。
参照している3つ目の記事に書かれているimportを同様に組み込んでください。
[PythonでOutlookの指定したアカウントの下に下書きを作る](https://gist.github.com/akilab/529c6954ddbc6024a0e8e2a381126e83)

Wordに貼り付けたテキストが約25文字で改行される件は、Word文書のページ書式がそうなっているのでは？ 例えばメモ帳とかテキストエディタの編集画面に貼り付けたならそうしたことにはならないでしょう。

そしてそれは当初の質問内容とは違ったものになっているので、必要ならば新たな質問として記事を立ててください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。pre-release版を使用後上記try文で翻訳してprint(result)で確認したところ翻訳文章を作成することができました。その後NameError
name 'pythoncom' is not definedが発生しました。